# How to wire up a function from a controller to a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a function I need to run on a custom directive.  I cannot get the function to pass through to the directive with isolate scope.

Here is my function I want to pass:

```
    function isGreaterThanStartDate() {
      console.log('function run');
    }
```

Here is the directive:

```
    am.directive('mtzDatePicker', [
      () => {
        return {
          replace: true,
          restrict: 'AE',
          templateUrl: 'feature/share/directives/datepicker.html',
          scope: {
            fixPosition: '=',
            name: '@',
            minDate: '=',
            mode: '@',
            blur: '&',
            ngChange: '&',
            ngModel: '=',
            placeholder: '@',
            readonly: '=',
            required: '='
          },
          link(scope) {
            scope.showWeeks = false;

            // Fix the model.
    const model = scope.ngModel;
    if (model instanceof Date) {
      model.setHours(0);
      model.setMinutes(0);
      model.setSeconds(0);
      model.setMilliseconds(0);
    }

    scope.changed = () => scope.ngChange();

    scope.popupOpen = false;

    scope.openDatePicker = event => {
      // Hide all the date pickers, in case any were already visible.
      $('.date-picker > .dropdown-menu').hide();

      // Prevent the click event that trigger this from bubbling.
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();

      scope.popupOpen = true;
    };
  }
};
```

and the html:

```
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="program-end-date" class="control-label">
      {{::'Promotion End Date' | L10n}}
    </label>
    <div mtz-date-picker name="endDate"
      ng-model="data.program.endDate"
      blur="isGreaterThanStartDate()"
      min-date="data.program.startDate">
      <!--readonly="data.readonly">-->
    </div>
    <div class="small">
      {{::'program-end-date-meaning' | L10n}}
    </div>
  </div
```

finally the html for the directive:

```
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="program-end-date" class="control-label">
      {{::'Promotion End Date' | L10n}}
    </label>
    <div mtz-date-picker name="endDate"
      ng-model="data.program.endDate"
      blur="isGreaterThanStartDate()"
      min-date="data.program.startDate">
      <!--readonly="data.readonly">-->
    </div>
    <div class="small">
      {{::'program-end-date-meaning' | L10n}}
    </div>
  </div
```

Comment: Why `$scope.isGreaterThanStartDate = isGreaterThanStartDate` then use that in the view? Not sure what your issue is...

Answer (score 1):

If the function `isGreaterThanStartDate` doesn't have too much dependency in the controller I think it is better to put that inside a `service` which is used to share functions between different places.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the directive the function in your original HTML.

```
<div mtz-date-picker name="endDate"
  ng-model="data.program.endDate"
  blur="isGreaterThanStartDate()"
  min-date="data.program.startDate"
  is-greater-than-start-date="isGreaterThanStartDate()"
  >
  <!--readonly="data.readonly">-->
</div>
```

Then in your directive have it passed in through your scope.

```
scope: {
        isGreaterThanStartDate: '&',
        fixPosition: '=',
        name: '@',
        minDate: '=',
        mode: '@',
        blur: '&',
        ngChange: '&',
        ngModel: '=',
        placeholder: '@',
        readonly: '=',
        required: '='
      },
```